# SQL Server/ TypeORM - multiple joins. How should I format the query?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typeorm

I'm new on typeorm, maybe someone can resolve my problem.
I have this query and need to format it to TypeORM :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Municipios.Descricao AS Cidade
  ,Municipios.Estado
  ,Municipios.CodigoMunicipio
  ,EmpresaUnidades.CNPJ
  ,Empresa.MaximoHorasExtras
  ,EmpresaUnidades.CodigoEmpresa
  ,UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.ValorTaxaEntrega
  ,UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.ValorTaxaDevolucao
  ,UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.PercTaxaAdministrativa
  ,UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.SobConsulta
  ,UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoTipoDiversoTaxaEntrega
  ,UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoTipoDiversoTaxaDevolucao
  ,EmpresaUnidades.CodigoMunicipio AS CodigoMunicipioEmpresa
  FROM UnidadesCidadeAtendimento
  INNER JOIN Municipios ON UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoMunicipio = Municipios.CodigoMunicipio
  INNER JOIN EmpresaUnidades ON UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoUnidade = EmpresaUnidades.CodigoUnidade
        AND UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoEmpresa = EmpresaUnidades.CodigoEmpresa
  INNER JOIN Empresa ON EmpresaUnidades.CodigoEmpresa = Empresa.CodigoEmpresa
  WHERE (EmpresaUnidades.Ativa = 'S')
  AND (UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.Ativa = 'S')
  AND (EmpresaUnidades.ExibirUnidadeAppReserva = 'S')
ORDER BY Municipios.Descricao
```

This is my try:

```
await this.createQueryBuilder('UnidadesCidadeAtendimento')
  .addSelect('Municipios.Descricao AS Cidade')
  .addSelect('Municipios.Estado')
  .addSelect('Municipios.CodigoMunicipio')
  .addSelect('EmpresaUnidades.CNPJ')
  .addSelect('Empresa.MaximoHorasExtras')
  .addSelect('EmpresaUnidades.CodigoEmpresa')
  .addSelect('UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.ValorTaxaEntrega')
  .addSelect('UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.ValorTaxaDevolucao')
  .addSelect('UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.PercTaxaAdministrativa')
  .addSelect('UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.SobConsulta')
  .addSelect('UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoTipoDiversoTaxaEntrega')
  .addSelect('UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoTipoDiversoTaxaDevolucao')
  .addSelect('EmpresaUnidades.CodigoMunicipio AS CodigoMunicipioEmpresa')
  .innerJoin('Municipios', 'UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoMunicipio = Municipios.CodigoMunicipio')
  .innerJoin('EmpresaUnidades', 'UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoUnidade = EmpresaUnidades.CodigoUnidade')
  .innerJoin('EmpresaUnidades', 'UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoEmpresa = EmpresaUnidades.CodigoEmpresa')
  .innerJoin('Empresa', 'EmpresaUnidades.CodigoEmpresa = Empresa.CodigoEmpresa')
  .where('EmpresaUnidades.Ativa = S')
  .distinct(true)
  .orderBy('Municipios.Estado', 'ASC')
  .getMany();
```

I receive this response:
"error": "Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'."

But i can't find the Syntax Error.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's not clear from your question, what "this" is.

Comment: I think problem is here : .where('EmpresaUnidades.Ativa = S'). You must use 'S' instead of S'

Answer (score 1):

Turn on TypeOrm full logging so you can see the actual generated SQL and you will quickly solve problems like this. See [TypeOrm logging](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md).

If you are not declaring your related tables as entities, you need to use the 3-argument form of the `innerJoin()` function, i.e. `.innerJoin(table, tableAlias, condition)`; make the table alias the same as the table name, and your inner joins look like this:

```
.innerJoin('Municipios',      'Municipios',      'UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoMunicipio = Municipios.CodigoMunicipio')
.innerJoin('EmpresaUnidades', 'EmpresaUnidades', 'UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoUnidade = EmpresaUnidades.CodigoUnidade')
.innerJoin('EmpresaUnidades', 'EmpresaUnidades', 'UnidadesCidadeAtendimento.CodigoEmpresa = EmpresaUnidades.CodigoEmpresa')
.innerJoin('Empresa',         'Empresa',         'EmpresaUnidades.CodigoEmpresa = Empresa.CodigoEmpresa')
```

Also, you missed the quotes for the Where value. You need to enclose the literal in single quotes, or parameterize it. If you are using the single quote literal, the where expression needs to be in double quotes:

```
.where("EmpresaUnidades.Ativa = 'S'")
```

Or alternatively to make it parameterized string (you can use single quotes because you are not using a SQL Server literal string):

```
.where('EmpresaUnidades.Ativa = :WhereAtiva', { WhereAtiva: 'S'})
```

Or make it a parameterized value:

```
var whereAtiva = 'S';

// the query ...

.where('EmpresaUnidades.Ativa = :WhereAtiva', { WhereAtiva: whereAtiva})
```